# Running Functional Coded UI scripts

Tags: visual-studio-2012, coded-ui-tests

Lets say we have 100 functional Coded UI scripts.  What kind of infrastructure is needed to run these tests in parallel?  I'm afraid it would take down Visual Studio Server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because coded UI interacts with a UI, only one instance can run on a machine at a time. If you set up a lab, or VM instances all running parts of your test your limit is # of instances and how much your application under test can handle.